# Rails gem error while trying to upgrade rails project to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

While trying to upgrade rails project from rails 2.3.5 to rails 3.0.3 i get following error:-

> /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in
>   `activate': can't activate rails (=
>   2.3.5, runtime) for [], already activated rails-3.0.3 for []
>   (Gem::LoadError)  from
>   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in`
>   require'     from
>   ./script/../config/boot.rb:54:in
>   `load_initializer'    from
>   ./script/../config/boot.rb:38:in`run'
>     from ./script/../config/boot.rb:11:in
>   `boot!'   from
>   ./script/../config/boot.rb:109    from
>   script/server:2:in`require'  from
>   script/server:2

The application is using ruby-enterprise-1.8.7. Can any one point out why rails 2.3.5 is being loaded, even though rails 3.0.3 is specified.

Thanks in advance,
Anubhaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you upgrade? It looks like your `config/boot.rb` is unchanged, which means it will attempt to load Rails 2.3.5. There are **significant** changes in the files in the `config` directory between Rails 2 and 3.

In my experience it's easier to create a new Rails 3 application, and copy all functionality (models, controllers, views, tests, ...) to this new application. It'll save you trouble and can be done very quickly.